# how to fix PHP & MYSQL code error select from the wrong table in database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, fetch

i have a PHP code with MYSQL where it select from the database using dropdown list using AJAX and display the result on screen.
i have 3 dropdown list dependent on each other. and each dropdown has its own table to select from it.
tables are:

- site_info
- owner_info
- company_info

**note :** the third table has only 6 values

the problem is when the user select from the firs dropdown the third one select and display the result of the second table.

anyone can help me to fix this problem.

## search_info_location.php

```
 <td><select id="site_name"  name = "site_name">
                      <option value="">Select Site</option>
                 <?php


                     $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results("select DISTINCT 
                        i.siteNAME, 
                        i.ownerID, 
                        i.companyID,
                        o.ownerNAME,
                        x.companyNAME
                       from site_info i
                       LEFT  
                       JOIN owner_info o
                       on i.ownerID = o.ownerID
                       LEFT  
                       JOIN company_info x
                       on i.companyID = x.companyID
                       ");
                      foreach($query_site_name as $row)
                      {

                          echo "<option value = '".$row ->companyID.",".$row ->ownerID.",".$row ->siteNAME."'>".$row->siteNAME."</option>";


                      } 


                 ?>

                </select></td>

<!--create  dropdown list owner names-->
                <td><select id="owner_name"  name ="owner_name">
                <option value="">Select Owner</option>
                </select></td>

<!--create  dropdown list Company names-->
                <td><select id="Company_name"  name ="Company_name">
                <option value="">Select Company</option>
                </select></td>



$sql = $wpdb->prepare("select i.siteID
     , i.siteNAME
     , i.equipmentTYPE
     , c.latitude
     , c.longitude
     , c.height 
     , o.ownerNAME
     , o.ownerCONTACT
     , x.companyNAME
     , y.subcontractorCOMPANY
     , y.subcontractorNAME
     , y.subcontractorCONTACT
  from site_info i
  LEFT  
  JOIN owner_info o
    on i.ownerID = o.ownerID
  LEFT  
  JOIN company_info x
    on i.companyID = x.companyID
  LEFT 
  JOIN subcontractor_info y
    on i.subcontractorID = y.subcontractorID
    LEFT JOIN site_coordinates2 c
    on i.siteID=c.siteID 
    where 
    i.siteNAME = %s
    AND 
    o.ownerNAME = %s
    AND 
    x.companyNAME = %s
   ",$site_name,$owner_name,$company_name);

 $query_submit =$wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);

<script type="text/javascript">

// make Dropdownlist depend on each other
$(document).ready(function(){


 // depend owner name on site name  
   $('#site_name').change(function(){
     var arrayId = $(this).val().split(",");
     if(arrayId != ""){
       var ownerID = arrayId[0];    //0
       var companyID = arrayId[1];  //1

     $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/dropdown_fetch_owner.php",
       method:"POST",
       data:{ownerID:ownerID,companyID:companyID},
       dataType:"text",
       success:function(data){
                 var Response = data.split("--");
                 $('#owner_name').html(Response[2]);
                 $('#Company_name').html(Response[4]);
        }
     });


   }


  });

});

</script>
```

## dropdown_fetch.php

```
<?php
 include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-load.php');
 global $wpdb,$owner_name,$company_name;

   $sql =$wpdb->get_results("select ownerID, ownerNAME from owner_info where ownerID = '".$_POST['ownerID']."' ORDER BY ownerNAME");
   $owner_name = '--Owner--';

  foreach($sql as $row){


      $owner_name.= "<option value ='".$row ->ownerID."'>".$row->ownerNAME."</option>";
  }
  echo $owner_name;


   $sql =$wpdb->get_results("select companyID, companyNAME from company_info where companyID = '".$_POST['companyID']."' ORDER BY companyNAME");
   $company_name = '--Company--';
   var_dump($sql);


   foreach($sql as $row){

     $company_name.= "<option value ='".$row ->companyID."'>".$row->companyNAME."</option>";
   }
   echo $company_name;
   exit();

?>
```

[image]

the maximum number of the companyID must be **6** however it display **166**  WHERE THIS IS NUMBER EXIST IN THE **owner_info table**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these two values flipped around...

```
   var ownerID = arrayId[0];    //0
   var companyID = arrayId[1];  //1
```

As your populating them the other way round...

```
echo "<option value = '".$row ->companyID.",".$row ->ownerID.",".$row ->siteNAME."'>".$row->siteNAME."</option>";
```

It should probably be

```
   var companyID = arrayId[0];
   var ownerID = arrayId[1];
```

Comment: you where right and the problem also was that the server made a cache  that i did not delete it so every time was displaying the caching page